# Debounce not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, debouncing

I have two Fiddle.

In the first Fiddle, debounce is working perfectly:

http://jsfiddle.net/hYsRh/4/

But when I remodify it a bit, the debounce doesn't work properly:

http://jsfiddle.net/hYsRh/272/

Can anybody tell me what's wrong in the second debouce Fiddle?

I want the script in this format in the second fiddle, under the on function of scroll like this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() 
{

});
```

Comment: Why are you trying to split the debouncing function? The debouncing function has to latch onto an event handler, like scroll, in order to take effect—as it passes whatever that is contained within in back to the event handler, but when certain timing conditions are met. `$.debounce` itself, when not attached to an event handler, has nowhere to return the funtion to.

Answer (score 2):

Don't add you code as a call back function, add it as a statement:
use this code:

```
$(window).on('scroll', $.debounce( 250, true, function(){
    $('#scrollMsg').html('SCROLLING!');
} ));
  $(window).on('scroll', $.debounce( 250, function(){
    $('#scrollMsg').html('DONE!');
} ));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hfLdwz5v/)**

Comment: so it is almost like the first fiddle that user modified